# Закрепленное меню и соседний div

Tags: css

Есть закрепленный див (`position: fixed;`) например высотой `20px`, он закрывает начало на `20px` обычного следующего блока. Подскажите как можно исправить?

Сейчас беру новый див с `20px`. Fixed его перекрывает и выходит норм

Comment: Если это для навигации, то советую использовать `position: sticky`

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: не за что, я опубликую как ответ тогда, раз помог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае стоит использовать `css` свойство `position` со значением `sticky`;

```
position: sticky;
```

Answer (score 2):

`position: sticky;` - хорошее быстрое решение, но с поддержкой браузерами у него пока проблемы, поэтому на продакшене лучше пойти через js, тем более, что понадобится 10 строчек ванилы.

```js
var node = document.getElementById('menu_sticky'),
  nodeOffs = node.offsetTop;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scrollPos = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0);
  if (scrollPos > nodeOffs) {
    node.classList.add('_stickied');
  } else {
    node.classList.remove('_stickied');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 300px 0 0 0;
  margin:0;
  height: 200vh;
}
.menu._sticky {
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}

.menu._sticky._stickied {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu _header _sticky" id="menu_sticky"></nav>
```